# Using Python's PIL, how do I enhance the contrast/saturation of an image?

Tags: python, algorithm, image, python-imaging-library

Just a simple contrast and saturation enhancement.
Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since PIL is dead for the most part. Install the Pillow fork instead, `sudo pip install pillow`, and use its ImageEnhance module http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageEnhance.html

```
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
>>> image = Image.open('downloads/jcfeb2011.jpg')
>>> contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
>>> image.show()
```

[image: (unenhanced)]

```
>>> contrast.enhance(2).show()
```

[image: (contrast enhanced)]

Comment: this is the reason, why you shouldn't post just links as an answer...it's useless now..

Comment: What if the contrast of the input image is already good ? How to detect if the image needs this ?

Comment: that would be subjective, and extremely difficult. in any case, it should be a separate question.